# TLsharp Console to send message

Tags: c#, telegram

I am trying to use the TLsharp library to send a telegram via a simple C# console app. My program runs but i receive not messages. I have gone through the process of creating an app on the Telegram website and received the necessary hash id and code.Please assist

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TeleSharp.TL;
using TLSharp;
using TLSharp.Core;

   namespace TLsharpTest
    {
       class Program
      {

    const int apiId = 55xxx;
    const int groupId = -167xxxxx;
    const string apiHash = "220xxxxxxxx";
    const string number = "27xxxxxxx";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var client = new TelegramClient(apiId, apiHash);
        client.ConnectAsync();


        var hash = client.SendCodeRequestAsync(number);
        var code = "55xxx"; // you can change code in debugger
        var user = client.MakeAuthAsync(number, apiHash, code);
        client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerUser() { user_id = groupId },             "TEST");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the users's access_hash to send messages. It should look like this:

```
 _client.SendMessageAsync(
                new TLInputPeerUser()
                {
                    user_id = channelUser.Id,
                    access_hash = channelUser.AccessHash
                }
```